Dirichlet inverse of $(-1)^n \mu(n)$
I have just started learning about Dirichlet series, convolutions, and inverses, and their applications. For example, the Riemann zeta function is the Dirichlet series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{n^s}}$, so $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}}$, since $1*\mu=\varepsilon$. At this point I decided to consider this function: $$f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\mu(n)}{n^s}}$$
Subtracting it from $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ gives: $$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}-f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{\mu(n)(1+(-1)^n)}{n^s}}=\mu(2)2^{1-s}\times\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$$
$\mu(2)=-1$, and solving for $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$, $$\frac{1+2^{1-s}}{\zeta(s)}=f(s)$$
Now I want to go back to $\zeta(s)$ is terms of another Dirichlet series $g(s)$ $$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{(1+2^{1-s})f(s)}=\frac{g(s)}{1+2^{1-s}}$$
But to reciprocate $f(s)$, I need the Dirichlet inverse of $(-1)^{n+1}\mu(n)$,
which I shall call $G(n)$. I found the first 15 terms recursively, and the best match I can find on the OEIS is A309873, which is one to one for the first 15 terms at least. But I have no clue where to start when it comes to actually proving this?  Where would I even begin?

Let $a(n) = (-1)^{n+1} \mu(n)$. We can prove that the inverse of $a(n)$ is characterized as the unique completely multiplicative function $b$ such that $b(2)=-1$ and $b(p)=1$ for $p>2$, that means that if we write $n=2^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}$ then $$b(n)=(-1)^{\alpha_1}$$
Proof:
Since $b$ is completely multiplicative we have that $b^{-1} = b\cdot\mu$ and is multiplicative. Notice that $a$ is also multiplicative. Lets prove that both coincide for prime powers:
For $\alpha>1$ and any prime $p$ we have $b(p^\alpha)\mu(p^\alpha) =b(p^\alpha)\cdot 0 = 0$ and $a(p^\alpha)=(-1)^{p^\alpha+1}\mu(p^\alpha)=(-1)^{p^\alpha+1}\cdot 0=0$
$b(2)\mu(2) = (-1)(-1)=1$ and $a(2)=(-1)^{2+1}\mu(2)=(-1)(-1)=1$.
For $p$ an odd prime
$b(p)\mu(p) = 1\cdot(-1)=-1$ and $a(p)=(-1)^{p+1}\mu(p)=1\cdot(-1)=-1$.
This proves that $b^{-1}= a$, so $a^{-1}=b$.

Assuming $a(1)\ne 0$, the Dirichlet inverse of $a(n)$ can be evaluated recursively (see Dirichlet inverse) as
$$a^{(-1)}(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{a(1)} & n=1 \\
 -\frac{1}{a(1)} \sum\limits_{\substack{d|n \\ d<n}} a\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\, a^{(-1)}(d) & n>1 \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{1}$$

Your question isn't clear because the title doesn't match the last paragraph, so both cases are addressed below.

I believe for
$$a(n)=(-1)^{n+1}\, \mu(n)\tag{2}$$
the Dirichlet inverse of $a(n)$ can be evaluated as
$$a^{(-1)}(n)=(-1)^{\text{IntegerExponent}[n,2]}\tag{3}$$
where $(-1)^{\text{IntegerExponent}[n,2]}$ corresponds to OEIS Entry A309873 and IntegerExponent(n,2) gives the highest power of $2$ that divides $n$.

I've verified formula (3) above against formula (1) above for $1\le n\le 10,000$.

The Dirichlet series related to formulas (2) and (3) above are
$$f(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a(n)}{n^s}=\frac{2^s+1}{2^s-1}\, \frac{1}{\zeta (s)}\,,\quad\Re(s)\ge 1\tag{4}$$
and
$$f^{(-1)}(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^{(-1)}(n)}{n^s}=\frac{2^s-1}{2^s+1}\, \zeta(s)\,,\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{5}.$$

Formulas (4) and (5) above imply $\zeta(s)$ can be evaluated as
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{2^s+1}{\left(2^s-1\right)\, f(s)}=\frac{\left(2^s+1\right)\, f^{-1}(s)}{2^s-1}\tag{6}.$$

I believe for
$$a(n)=(-1)^n\, \mu(n)\tag{7}$$
the Dirichlet inverse of $a(n)$ can be evaluated as
$$a^{(-1)}(n)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 (-1)^{\text{IntegerExponent}\left(\frac{n}{2},2\right)} & 2|n \\
 -1 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{8}.$$

I've verified formula (8) above against formula (1) above for $1\le n\le 10,000$.

The Dirichlet series related to formulas (7) and (8) above are
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a(n)}{n^s}=-\frac{2^s+1}{2^s-1}\, \frac{1}{\zeta (s)}\,,\quad\Re(s)\ge 1\tag{9}$$
and
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^{(-1)}(n)}{n^s}=-\frac{2^s-1}{2^s+1}\, \zeta(s)\,,\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{10}.$$

Here's an approach to finding the formula for the Dirichlet inverse that is (I think) better in that we discover the formula rather than having to figure it out first and then prove it.
$a(n) = (-1)^{n+1} \mu(n)$ is the product of two multiplicative functions and is thus multiplicative. Therefore its Dirichlet inverse $b(n)$ is also multiplicative, so it suffices to calculate it on prime powers $p^k$. From the definition of Dirichlet inverse, for $k\ge1$ we must have
$$
0 = \sum_{d\mid p^k} a(d)b(p^k/d) = \sum_{j=0}^k a(p^j) b(p^{k-j}) = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{p^j+1}\mu(p^j) b(p^{k-j}) = b(p^k) + (-1)^p b(p^{k-1}).
$$
Starting with $b(1)=1$, it's now easy to prove inductively that $b(2^k) = (-1)^k$ for all $k$ and that $b(p^k) = 1$ for all odd prime powers $p^k$.
